# Typhoon is not working

Tags: objective-c, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, typhoon

How are you?

I have strange stories with typhoon framework.

I make this way

1) Create classes use GENERAMBA (VIPER templates)

2) Create UIViewController on storyboard

3) Make runtime attribute called typhoonKey

[image]

4) Next named storyboard by class

[image]

5) Next time I add my Assembly class in plist

[image]

6) Try start my project, but...

[image]

//text
2018-04-19 10:40:29.436958+0300 BeeBooks Dev[6472:1952490] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't find definition for specified selector viewBookshelf'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1854e6d8c 0x1846a05ec 0x1854e6c6c 0x1046ebc50 0x104716008 0x104716240 0x104716240 0x104715c9c 0x1047157a8 0x10470fda0 0x18f497fd8 0x18f0b5254 0x18f083550 0x18f6b3a0c 0x18f082e4c 0x18f082ce8 0x18f081b78 0x18fd1772c 0x18f081268 0x18fafc9b8 0x18fc4aae8 0x18f080c88 0x18f080624 0x18f07d65c 0x18f07d3ac 0x187ce4470 0x187cecd6c 0x1052ad220 0x1052b9850 0x187d18878 0x187d1851c 0x187d18ab8 0x18548f404 0x18548ec2c 0x18548c79c 0x1853acda8 0x18738f020 0x18f38d78c 0x1045a2e94 0x184e3dfc0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure your Assembly has Definition for that key? Can you try running your app without Storyboard and try to resolve your definition named "viewBookshelf" manually? Let's isolate the problem.

Comment: ty for advice. When I remove typhoon key in storyboard, my program working is correct.

Comment: @Aleksey, off-topic, but do you mind taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550755/is-ios-state-restoration-possible-in-ios-library-could-not-find-a-storyboard ?